# Frequent OEM agent down alert

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-enterprise-manager

We are getting frequent agent down alerts from OEM for oracle database servers. When login to the server and check the agent will be running without issues. How can we stop these false alerts?

Comment: You might want to look at the agent log files on the target and see if there are any error messages. It's possible the alerts are "real", but the agents restart so quickly that by the time you look everything appears to be fine. I used to get this issue a lot but I can't remember how my organization solved it - I think maybe we increased a Java memory parameter?